# Why is blender not rendering the light source in certain frames?

Tags: rendering, animation

As said in title blender is not rendering the light source in certain frames and there is no distinguishable pattern to the frames that are missing the light source.
First two frames Exhibiting this behavior. are 2 and 13 of 250.
I will continue to attempt to solve this issue however Any info you may have on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

(in the file "Green.7z" the image titled "Green" was used to texture the uv sphere just because it looked better then just using defuse.I was just trying to make something that looked interesting that was simple. Feel free to play around with the project yourselves and make something better of it if this issue gets resolved.) (I labeled the project files as "(Corrupted)" so i could recreate the project without confusion.)

Blender Project files:

Please go to the link provided to download all related files to the project described.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6UXTR3VWO_DODNtQW1DZnd2cUk

(3.54 GB)

Render Engine: Cicles

System info:

OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name MS0001
System Manufacturer Gateway
System Model    DX4831
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU         750  @ 2.67GHz, 2668 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. P01-A0, 11/17/2009
SMBIOS Version  2.6
Locale  United States
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   16.0 GB
Available Physical Memory   13.2 GB
Total Virtual Memory    31.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory    28.9 GB
Page File Space 16.0 GB

GPU:

Name    NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660
Adapter Type    GeForce GTX 660, NVIDIA compatible
Adapter Description NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660
Adapter RAM (2,147,483,648) bytes
Driver Version  21.21.13.7849
Color Table Entries 4294967296
Resolution  1280 x 1024 x 60 hertz
Bits/Pixel  32
Cores       960

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using blender version: 2.78a and have installed filmic blender in blender.

Comment: Replace all objects with a cube, narrow down the problem. And reduce the file size. Does the problem remain with 1 light and 1 cube, then upload that file!

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the emission shader for the fluid domain.

Comment: The light source and the emission shader on the fluid domain cant coexist in certain frames. I seemingly can only have one or the other.